# Prevent delegation handlers call for specific Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have many Web API controllers and many global delegating handlers for them.
But for 1 controller i need to prevent of calling some (or any) of these handlers.
In case if handlers are working on bubbling scheme i'd like to prevent bubbling and specify custom DoNotBubbleHandler for my controller, or just specify which handlers i'd like to use for this controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try defining per-route handlers like shown [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers), in the `Per-Route Message Handlers`.

Basically, for your particular controller you can specify a different set of handlers than the ones registered globally:

```
// Custom handlers for the special controller.
DelegatingHandler[] handlers = new DelegatingHandler[] {
   new MessageHandler3()
};

// Create a message handler chain with an end-point.
var routeHandlers = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), handlers);

//This should be only the controller you want to use a different delegating handler
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route2",
    routeTemplate: "api2/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    handler: routeHandlers
);

//global message handler
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandler1());
```